# how to order software versions in python when they have two digits

Tags: python

I have an array of version numbers that includes alphanumeric components, and I want to sort them from newer to older. However, I'm encountering issues where versions have double digits like: vers. "10.X.X" appear before "11.X.X".
I tried different solutions proposed here and on line but with no success.

Here's the array of versions I'm working with:

```
versions = ['11.4.0', '11.3.2', '11.3.1', '11.3.0', '11.2.0', '11.1.0', '11.0.0', '10.16.2', '10.16.1', '10.16.0', '10.15.0', '10.14.1', '10.14.0', '10.13.0', '10.12.0', '10.11.0', '10.10.0', '10.9.1', '10.9.0', '10.8.0', '4.7.6', '4.7.5', '4.7.4', '4.7.3', '4.7.2', '4.7.1', '5.4.0', '5.3.3', '5.3.2', '5.3.1', '5.3.0', '5.2.2', '5.2.1', '5.2.0', '5.1.18', '5.1.17', '5.1.16', '5.1.15', '5.1.13', '5.1.12', '5.1.11', '5.1.10', '5.1.9', '5.1.4', '5.1.0', '5.0.0', '5.9.0', '5.8.0', '5.7.1', '5.7.0', '5.6.5', '5.6.4', '5.6.3', '5.6.2', '5.6.1', '5.6.0', '5.5.9', '5.5.8', '5.5.7', '5.5.6', '5.5.5', '5.5.4', '5.5.3', '5.5.2', '5.5.1', '5.5.0', '7.4.2', '7.4.1', '7.4.0', '7.3.0', '7.2.1', '7.2.0', '7.1.0', '7.0.3', '7.0.2', '7.0.1', '7.0.0', '6.2.0', '6.1.2', '6.1.0', '6.0.0', '5.14.0', '5.13.0', '5.12.0', '5.11.0', '5.10.0', '7.9.5', '7.9.4', '7.9.3', '7.9.2', '7.9.1', '7.9.0', '7.8.4', '7.8.3', '7.8.2', '7.8.1', '7.8.0', '7.7.1', '7.7.0', '7.6.3', '7.6.2', '7.6.1', '7.6.0', '7.5.0', '7.4.4', '7.4.3', '8.3.3', '8.3.2', '8.3.1', '8.3.0', '8.2.0', '8.1.4', '8.1.3', '8.1.2', '8.1.1', '8.1.0', '8.0.8', '8.0.7', '8.0.6', '8.0.5', '8.0.4', '8.0.3', '8.0.2', '8.0.0', '7.9.8', '7.9.7', '9.5.2', '9.5.1', '9.5.0', '9.4.0', '9.3.1', '9.3.0', '9.2.6', '9.2.5', '9.2.4', '9.2.3', '9.2.2', '9.2.1', '9.2.0', '9.1.0', '9.0.0', '8.5.1', '8.5.0', '8.4.0', '8.3.5', '8.3.4', '10.7.0', '10.6.2', '10.6.1', '10.6.0', '10.5.0', '10.4.0', '10.3.0', '10.2.0', '10.1.0', '10.0.5', '10.0.4', '10.0.3', '10.0.1', '10.0.0', '9.8.3', '9.8.2', '9.8.1', '9.8.0', '9.7.0', '9.6.0']
```

I've attempted different approaches using lambda functions, as well as libraries like StrictVersion, natsort, and semantic_version. However, none of these methods give me the desired ordering, where versions starting with "11.X.X" come before "10.X.X" and the rest (e.g., "9.X.X", "8.X.X", etc.). Here's an example of what I've tried:

Using StrictVersion from distutils.version:

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion

def order_versions(versions):
    return sorted(versions, key=StrictVersion)
```

Using natsort:

```
from natsort import natsorted

def order_versions(versions):
    ordered_versions = natsorted(versions, reverse=True)
    return ordered_versions
```

Using semantic_version from packaging.version:

```
from packaging.version import Version

def order_versions(versions):
    ordered_versions = sorted(versions, key=Version, reverse=True)
    return ordered_versions
```

the best I get is:

```
versions = ['10.0.5', '10.0.4', '10.0.3', '10.0.1', '10.0.0', '10.1.0', '10.2.0', '10.3.0', '10.4.0', '10.5.0', '10.6.2', '10.6.1', '10.6.0', '10.7.0', '10.8.0', '10.9.1', '10.9.0', '10.10.0', '10.11.0', '10.12.0', '10.13.0', '10.14.1', '10.14.0', '10.15.0', '10.16.2', '10.16.1', '10.16.0', '11.0.0', '11.1.0', '11.2.0', '11.3.2', '11.3.1', '11.3.0', '11.4.0', '4.7.6', '4.7.5', '4.7.4', '4.7.3', '4.7.2', '4.7.1', '5.0.0', '5.1.18', '5.1.17', '5.1.16', '5.1.15', '5.1.13', '5.1.12', '5.1.11', '5.1.10', '5.1.9', '5.1.4', '5.1.0', '5.2.2', '5.2.1', '5.2.0', '5.3.3', '5.3.2', '5.3.1', '5.3.0', '5.4.0', '5.5.9', '5.5.8', '5.5.7', '5.5.6', '5.5.5', '5.5.4', '5.5.3', '5.5.2', '5.5.1', '5.5.0', '5.6.5', '5.6.4', '5.6.3', '5.6.2', '5.6.1', '5.6.0', '5.7.1', '5.7.0', '5.8.0', '5.9.0', '5.10.0', '5.11.0', '5.12.0', '5.13.0', '5.14.0', '6.0.0', '6.1.2', '6.1.0', '6.2.0', '7.0.3', '7.0.2', '7.0.1', '7.0.0', '7.1.0', '7.2.1', '7.2.0', '7.3.0', '7.4.2', '7.4.1', '7.4.0', '7.4.4', '7.4.3', '7.5.0', '7.6.3', '7.6.2', '7.6.1', '7.6.0', '7.7.1', '7.7.0', '7.8.4', '7.8.3', '7.8.2', '7.8.1', '7.8.0', '7.9.5', '7.9.4', '7.9.3', '7.9.2', '7.9.1', '7.9.0', '7.9.8', '7.9.7', '8.0.8', '8.0.7', '8.0.6', '8.0.5', '8.0.4', '8.0.3', '8.0.2', '8.0.0', '8.1.4', '8.1.3', '8.1.2', '8.1.1', '8.1.0', '8.2.0', '8.3.3', '8.3.2', '8.3.1', '8.3.0', '8.3.5', '8.3.4', '8.4.0', '8.5.1', '8.5.0', '9.0.0', '9.1.0', '9.2.6', '9.2.5', '9.2.4', '9.2.3', '9.2.2', '9.2.1', '9.2.0', '9.3.1', '9.3.0', '9.4.0', '9.5.2', '9.5.1', '9.5.0', '9.6.0', '9.7.0', '9.8.3', '9.8.2', '9.8.1', '9.8.0']
```

Unfortunately, none of these methods produce the desired ordering. How can I correctly order this array of version numbers in Python, ensuring that "11.X.X" appears before "10.X.X" and the rest follow accordingly?

Comment: _"I want to sort them from newer to older"_ - `sorted(versions, key=StrictVersion, reverse=True)`? That _does_ seem to give your desired ordering.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the desired code:

```
versions = ['11.4.0', '11.3.2', '11.3.1', '11.3.0', '11.2.0', '11.1.0', '11.0.0', '10.16.2', '10.16.1', '10.16.0', '10.15.0', '10.14.1', '10.14.0', '10.13.0', '10.12.0', '10.11.0', '10.10.0', '10.9.1', '10.9.0', '10.8.0', '4.7.6', '4.7.5', '4.7.4', '4.7.3', '4.7.2', '4.7.1', '5.4.0', '5.3.3', '5.3.2', '5.3.1', '5.3.0', '5.2.2', '5.2.1', '5.2.0', '5.1.18', '5.1.17', '5.1.16', '5.1.15', '5.1.13', '5.1.12', '5.1.11', '5.1.10', '5.1.9', '5.1.4', '5.1.0', '5.0.0', '5.9.0', '5.8.0', '5.7.1', '5.7.0', '5.6.5', '5.6.4', '5.6.3', '5.6.2', '5.6.1', '5.6.0', '5.5.9', '5.5.8', '5.5.7', '5.5.6', '5.5.5', '5.5.4', '5.5.3', '5.5.2', '5.5.1', '5.5.0', '7.4.2', '7.4.1', '7.4.0', '7.3.0', '7.2.1', '7.2.0', '7.1.0', '7.0.3', '7.0.2', '7.0.1', '7.0.0', '6.2.0', '6.1.2', '6.1.0', '6.0.0', '5.14.0', '5.13.0', '5.12.0', '5.11.0', '5.10.0', '7.9.5', '7.9.4', '7.9.3', '7.9.2', '7.9.1', '7.9.0', '7.8.4', '7.8.3', '7.8.2', '7.8.1', '7.8.0', '7.7.1', '7.7.0', '7.6.3', '7.6.2', '7.6.1', '7.6.0', '7.5.0', '7.4.4', '7.4.3', '8.3.3', '8.3.2', '8.3.1', '8.3.0', '8.2.0', '8.1.4', '8.1.3', '8.1.2', '8.1.1', '8.1.0', '8.0.8', '8.0.7', '8.0.6', '8.0.5', '8.0.4', '8.0.3', '8.0.2', '8.0.0', '7.9.8', '7.9.7', '9.5.2', '9.5.1', '9.5.0', '9.4.0', '9.3.1', '9.3.0', '9.2.6', '9.2.5', '9.2.4', '9.2.3', '9.2.2', '9.2.1', '9.2.0', '9.1.0', '9.0.0', '8.5.1', '8.5.0', '8.4.0', '8.3.5', '8.3.4', '10.7.0', '10.6.2', '10.6.1', '10.6.0', '10.5.0', '10.4.0', '10.3.0', '10.2.0', '10.1.0', '10.0.5', '10.0.4', '10.0.3', '10.0.1', '10.0.0', '9.8.3', '9.8.2', '9.8.1', '9.8.0', '9.7.0', '9.6.0']

for i in range(len(versions)):
    versions[i] = [int(i) for i in versions[i].split('.')]

versions.sort(reverse=True)

for i in range(len(versions)):
    versions[i] = '.'.join([str(i) for i in versions[i]])
```

Comment: Feel free to ask anything in comment if you don't understand any part of the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to python. You translated  a string into an array of 3 dimensions integer array (like matrix), ordered all sub arrays and then repacked it back, right?

Comment: @BogAlt yes.. that is what i am doing